# How many parameters does matrix [0, 1, 2] have?

Tags: matrices

I know it has rank 1 since there is 1 leading entry, but what about the number of parameter?
I want to say 2, but does the number 0 got me confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That matrix doesn't have any parameters.  In case you're asking for the dimension of its kernel, that's certainly $2$.  Don't confuse it with $$\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}.$$  The dimension of the kernel of this matrix is $0$.

Comment: Ah, now I see it.